# Convert a Promise<string> from superagent response to string in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a code like this
I am using [flickr-sdk](https://github.com/flickr/flickr-sdk/) which uses superagent to make all calls.

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
    var flickr= require('flickr-sdk');
    
    let userId: string = '123'
    getFavList: string = async() => {
    let favResponse: Response = await flickr.favorites.getList({
        user_id: userId,
    });
    return favResponse.text;
   }
```

Now I am calling it like this

```
let list: string = await getFavList();
```

Typescript gives me this error `() => Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Is there any way to convert Promise to string. May be after its resolved and then return that resolved value.

There a sample [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rvrkov?file=favS)

edit1: updated the code to return favResponse
edit2: fixed an error in code
edit3: added stack blitz

Comment: return `favResponse.text` instead of `Response.text`

Comment: Updated code. Error is there

Comment: Why did you declare `getFavList` as a `string` you assign a function? Or: Why did you make the value a function if you want a string? Please post the *complete* code, including the intended usage of `getFavList`.

Comment: I have added https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rvrkov?file=favS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited after OP added [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rvrkov?file=favS):

Two simple changes:

1. Use a lowercase `string` on this line:

```
async function getFavList(): Promise<String> { /* ... */ }
// becomes
async function getFavList(): Promise<string> { /* ... */ }
```

2. Change `string` to `Promise<string>` on this line:

```
async function abcd2(): string { /* ... */ }
// becomes
async function abcd2(): Promise<string> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I tried this and gives this error
Type '() => Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: @AhmedRana - make a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/typescript) that demonstrates your error, it's hard to tell what the problem is because your code isn't written that great.

Comment: If that helps https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rvrkov?file=favS

Comment: Thanks. I need to map to interface FavoritesList as in stackblitz. Since its a Promise, would it be possible to map it to that interface?